# Flutter app on MacOS return flutter.gradle error

Tags: flutter, macos, android-studio, dart

I am trying to run my flutter app on MacOS but it returns following error

> Script '/Users/macbookair/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1156

### Steps to Reproduce

1. Execute `flutter run`
2. Tried `flutter clean`
3. Tried `flutter pub get`
4. Tried `flutter pub upgrade`
5. Deleted `.build` `build` `.idea` `pubspec.lock` `.dart_tools` etc.
6. re-cloned my app from repository

**Expected results:**

App running!

**Actual results:**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/macbookair/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1156

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/macbookair/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

flutter doctor -v

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-arm, locale en)
    • Flutter version 3.0.5 at /Users/macbookair/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision f1875d570e (4 days ago), 2022-07-13 11:24:16 -0700
    • Engine revision e85ea0e79c
    • Dart version 2.17.6
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/macbookair/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.69.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.44.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • sdk gphone64 arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-arm64  • Android 12
      (API 32) (emulator)
    • macOS (desktop)             • macos         • darwin-arm64   • macOS 12.4
      21F79 darwin-arm
    • Chrome (web)                • chrome        • web-javascript • Google
      Chrome 103.0.5060.114

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Have you tried updating the dependencies of your project? I think this might be the issue

Comment: Can you share the complete error log from terminal?

Comment: @MilanSurelia I am using `audioplayers` if I update that my app will break

Comment: @MilanSurelia the error log I shared in `Actual results:` section

Comment: You need to do the changes in audioplayers package as it will not support the latest version of flutter.

Comment: Are you able to see only `Build Failed ` message in `Error Log` or anything prior to it?

Comment: @MilanSurelia what I sent in `Actual results:` section, that's all I'm able to see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246505/discussion-between-milan-surelia-and-mafortis).